# java lang NullPointerException involving abstract class?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, abstract-class

Now i know one can not initilize an abstract class. But i have been reading up on the java.lang.NullPointerException to which people say is caused by fields still pointing to null. I have initialized the inherited superclass methods via ComputerPart but i am still getting an error. I am taking online classes so your input is highly valued. Thank you.

```
abstract class Product {
    protected float price;
    public static int i = 0; // to keep count starts at zero 
    protected static int ID ; // to update and keep track of ID even if i changes 
    // return the price of a particular product
    abstract float price();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

class ComputerPart extends Product {

    public ComputerPart(float p) {
        i += 1; // each time constructor invoked ,  
        ID = i; // to update ID even if i changes.
        price = p;
    }

    public float price() { return price; }

    // a getter method so ID can be nicely formated and returned
    public static String getID(){ 
        String Identification =  "ID#" + ID;
        return Identification;
    }
}  

//------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.*;

public class GenericOrder <T extends Product>  {
    ArrayList<Product> genericOrder; 

    public String comPrice(float comPrice){
        genericOrder.add(new ComputerPart(comPrice));
        String s;
        s="Computer Part, Price=$ "+comPrice;
        return s;
    }
}
```

And my test class is

```
GenericOrder gen = new GenericOrder<Product>(); 
gen.comPrice(0);
```

Comment: Provide the code where the `NullPointerException` raises.

Comment: You never initialize `genericOrder`

Comment: genericOrder.add(new ComputerPart(comPrice));
this is a line from GenericOrder class

Comment: You can't _instantiate_ an abstract class - that is,  you can't make an object of that class.  You CAN _initialise_ a variable whose type is an abstract class.

Comment: @ZouZou you are right. That was the problem. Thank you for your time. As you can see i need to keep at this to not make silly mistakes like this thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The genericOrder is never initialized. Change

```
ArrayList<Product> genericOrder;
```

to

```
ArrayList<Product> genericOrder = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Comment: Or better: `List<Product> genericOrder = new ArrayList<Product>();` or `List<Product> genericOrder = new ArrayList<>();` (if Java 7 or sup).